# Silverlight: Accessing event payload in EventTrigger

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to access EventArgs of the event that EventTrigger is bound to? I have created a generic EventArgs class that let's me pass generic payload through to event handler. How can I access that in EventTrigger? Is there any extension that would allow me to do that?

```
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="AgentSelected" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=ctlAgentSearch, Path=DataContext}">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=bidAgentEditView}"  MethodName="ToggleSearchPanel"/>
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=text}" PropertyName=Text" 
Value=??? **Here I need to access EventArgs of the event that was raised?** />
            </i:EventTrigger>
```